# replace multiple values in a string

Tags: r, stringr

**What's the most syntactically simple way to replace multiple values in a string expression?**

Let's say I have:

```
string <- "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

And I want to replace all 1's, 2's, 3's, and 4's with '0'. I can use `stringr::str_replace()`:

```
string %>% 
  str_replace("1", "0") %>% 
  str_replace("2", "0") %>% 
  str_replace("3", "0") %>% 
  str_replace("4", "0")
```

What is a better way to do this kind of operation?

---

## EDIT:

### Joran's answer: use **`str_replace_all()`**

```
str_replace_all(string = string,pattern = "[1234]",replacement = "0")
```

---

### user2738526's answer: use **`gsub()`**

```
gsub("[1-4]","0",string)
```

Comment: `str_replace_all(string = string,pattern = "[1234]",replacement = "0")`...?

Comment: Brilliant. That does the trick. Want to put it as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted for others?

Comment: It's also very easy to do in base if you don't want to add a library unnecessarily `gsub("[1-4]","0",string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option would be `chartr`

```
chartr('1234', '0000', string)
#[1] "0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9"
```